# What can I do to make my object smoother in the render?

Tags: rendering, materials, resolution

I am a super beginner - would really appreciate help. I have this glass material object and I'm trying to create a render that is actually smooth. You can see in the image that the top right bits have some low-res looking edges. All around it, the edges are actually not looking very smooth.

I've played with:

- Render samples: I am rendering it at 1000samples.
- Light: I have one point light source off to the side at 500W.
- Material: The glass material is created by increasing transmission to 1 and reducing roughness.

I also see a reflection in the background - I would love help on removing the reflection as well. I tried making the background more grainy but I think that made things worse. Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I believe it has pretty much nothing to do with the number of samples or lighting. i would suggest you add a *Subdivision Subsurface* modifier to your glass object, set the *Render* value to $2$, and that's pretty much it.
[image]

As for a simple project like this, keeping the samples at 512 should be more than enough. As for the reflection in the background, just go to the *Principled BSDF* of the background and increase the *Roughness* to $0.5$ or more.

Comment: Thank you! Changing the Subdivision Surface modifier seems to have done it! Really appreciate it.

Comment: That's great to hear! I'm glad my Answer was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

By low res, do you mean that they aren't curvy enough, or just that the image is a bit grainy? If it's the latter, try using one of Blender's denoiser algorithms. If it's the former, then try increasing the geometry to smooth out the curve.

If it's actually the resolution then maybe increase the resolution of your render to output a larger image.

And as another person has said, increase the roughness of your ground material to lose the reflection.